# Storing MongoDB query in the database

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a collection `subscribers`.

I want to get a segment of subscribers by applying sometimes complex filters in the query `db.subscribers.find({ age: { $gt: 20 }, ...etc })`, but I don't want to save the result, since that would be inefficient.

Instead, I would like to save only the filters applied in the query as a set of rules in the `segments` collection.

Is that a good approach and what would be an efficient way to do that?

Should I just save the query object itself as a document or define a more restrictive schema before saving?

Comment: what kind of problem are you trying to solve with that approach?

Comment: First, I don't want to save the results of the query, since it will add unnecessary duplication of data over and over again. Secondly, the result needs to be dynamic and will be reused frequently, so it makes sense to somehow store the query and not the data itself.